# How can I switch targets using coroutine each x seconds?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FLookAnimator lookAnimator;
    public Transform[] targets;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitSome());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    IEnumerator WaitSome()
    {
        lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[0];

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);

        lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[1];
    }
}
```

This changes the targets every 10 seconds but it's doing it only once and I don't want to assign the target on my own like targets[0] and targets[1] in this case I have two targets but if I have 20 targets?

How can I loop in the Update over the targets and then every 10 seconds to change between all the targets. every 10 seconds change the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you meant to write something like...

```
IEnumerator SwitchTargetsPeriodically()
{        
    for (int i = 0; true; i = (i + 1) % targets.Length) {
        lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    }
}
```